# How do I implement this function using XOR gates?

Tags: logic, xor

I have to implement the function below with XOR gates. I drew the Karnaugh map and wrote down the resulting minimized function. But now I'm stuck with AND and OR gates, what should I do in order to get XOR gates?

[image: f]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution looks as follows:

```
F = Sum(1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14);

F = A' B' C' D + A' B' C D' + A' B C' D' + A' B C D + A B' C' D' + A B' C D + A B C' D + A B C D';

F = XOR(C, D) & A' B' + XOR(C, D) & A B  + XOR(A, B) & C' D' + XOR(A, B) & C D;

F = XOR(C, D) & XOR(A, B)'  + XOR(A, B) & XOR(C, D) ';

F = XOR(XOR(A, B), XOR(C, D));


    A B C D  XOR(A, B)  XOR(C, D)  F
00  0 0 0 0      0          0      0
01  0 0 0 1      0          1      1
02  0 0 1 0      0          1      1
03  0 0 1 1      0          0      0
04  0 1 0 0      1          0      1
05  0 1 0 1      1          1      0
06  0 1 1 0      1          1      0
07  0 1 1 1      1          0      1
08  1 0 0 0      1          0      1
09  1 0 0 1      1          1      0
10  1 0 1 0      1          1      0
11  1 0 1 1      1          0      1
12  1 1 0 0      0          0      0
13  1 1 0 1      0          1      1
14  1 1 1 0      0          1      1
15  1 1 1 1      0          0      0
```

A handy tool for such questions is "Logic Friday 1"